# JSF selectOneListBox listener doesn't get fired

Tags: jsf-2, listener

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer for my problem, All most all questions and answers are relates to selectOneMenu. Iam using selectOneListbox component in my page as shows below

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="basic" value="#{location.selectedCategory}" style="width: 400px; border: none;" >                                                                                   
    <f:selectItems value="#{location.categories}" var="y" itemLabel="#{y.title} (#{y.itemCount})" itemValue="#{y}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{location.onNodeSelect}"/>
    <f:ajax render="itemsPanel" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

My bean,

```
  @ManagedBean(name = "location")    
  @SessionScoped    
  public class LocationServiceBean extends BaseService implements Serializable{

    public void onNodeSelect(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {  
       log.info("Entering method : onNodeSelect : ");
       if(null != selectedCategory){
        GetCategoriesAndItemsResponse response =getLocationSupport().getItemsByCategoryAndLocation(selectedCategory.getId(), selectedLocationId);
            if(response.getStatusCode().equals("0"))
            {
                items = response.getData().getItems();
                log.info("Items size: " + items.size());
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Problem here is, above listener in the selectOneListBox doesn't get fired when i select items in the list box. Tried with primeface (3.5) component as well, but no luck.

UPDATE: added more code

```
<h:form id="venuForm" prependId="false">
                                                    <legend>2. Choose Venue</legend>
                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                        <label class="span3" for="Country">Venue</label>

                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{location.selectedLocationId}" id="select01" required="true"
                                                                requiredMessage="Location is a mandatory field" styleClass="span8">
                                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select Location" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                                                <f:selectItems value="#{location.allLocations}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.title}" itemValue="#{c.locationId}" />
                                                                <f:ajax listener="#{location.loadCategoriesListner}" render=":itemForm:categoriesPanel" execute="@this" />
                                                                <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":itemForm:itemsPanel" />
                                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </h:form>
                                                <h:form id="itemForm" prependId="false">
                                                    <legend>3. Choose Gift</legend>
                                                    <div class="control-group">

                                                        <p:outputPanel id="panel" autoUpdate="true">
                                                            <div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; border: none;">
                                                                <p:panel id="categoriesPanel" rendered="#{location.categories != null}" autoUpdate="true" style=" border: none;">
                                                                    <h:selectOneListbox id="basic"  value="#{location.selectedCategory}" style="width: 400px; border: none;">

                                                                        <f:selectItems value="#{location.categories}" var="y" itemLabel="#{y.title} (#{y.itemCount})" itemValue="#{y}" />
                                                                        <f:ajax listener="#{location.onNodeSelect}" render="itemsPanel" execute="@form" event="change"/>
                                                                    </h:selectOneListbox>

                                                                </p:panel>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                                        <div class="clear" style="height: 30px;"></div>

                                                        <div style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">
                                                            <p:panel id="itemsPanel" style="float: left;" header="Items">
                                                                <ui:repeat value="#{location.items}" var="o" id="itemTable">

                                                                    <div style="width: 170px; height: 200px; margin: auto; float: left; border-style: solid; border-color: #ECE5B6; border-width: thin;">
                                                                        <div style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px;">
                                                                            <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                                                <h:outputText value="#{fnc:getTitleTruncateText(o.title)}"  style="margin: 0 auto;  padding: 0 0 20px; color: #9A1326; width: 100px; font-size: 14px; text-align: center;" />
                                                                                <BR />
                                                                            </div>

                                                                            <div style="padding-left: 45px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                                                <h:graphicImage value="http://dev.cdn.abc.com/#{o.imageId}_3.png" id="itemImage" alt="#{o.title}" />
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div
                                                                                style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #FFC200; margin: 15px auto 0 auto; width: 100px; text-align: center; color: #29000F; border: 1px solid #F2BD00;">
                                                                                <h:outputText value="$ #{fnc:formatDoubleValue(o.salePrice)}" />
                                                                            </div>

                                                                            <div class="clear" style="height: 5px;"></div>
                                                                            <div style="float: left;">
                                                                                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 50px;">
                                                                                    <p:spinner id="itemQty" value="#{o.selectedQty}" size="3" min="1" max="#{o.qtyAvailable}" style="width: 20px;" />
                                                                                </div>

                                                                                <div style="float: right;">
                                                                                    <h:commandButton value="Add" id="addToCartBtn"  rendered="#{o.qtyAvailable > 0 }" actionListener="#{location.addItemToCart(o)}" />
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </ui:repeat>
                                                            </p:panel>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="clear" style="height: 30px;"></div>
                                                        <div style="float: right;">
                                                            <h:commandButton action="#{location.gotoUserDetails}" value="Next" onclick="return(validate());" rendered="#{!empty location.selectedItems}" />
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </h:form>
```

Comment: HI Nikola, Really appreciate your help.But I tried all the things, I have been testing this with firefox, there is no error in the firebug console, I even restarted the machine hoping it will work. But so far no good. I dont what else to be done, May i try your workaround with primeface? what need to be changed for primeface?

Comment: If that doesn't work see if selectedCategory is updated with new value after selecting, if it isn't showing new value you have to make a converter for your Category class and specify it in you component(google converters, jsf).

Comment: HI NikolaB, I changed `<f:selectItems value="#{location.categories}" var="y" itemLabel="#{y.title} (#{y.itemCount})" itemValue="#{y}" />` itemValue to get the id of the y object, like this `itemValue="#{y.Id}"`. Guess what, it worked. Also i used `<f:ajax listener="#{location.onNodeSelect}" event="change" render="itemsPanel" execute="@form"/>` as well. Its working now as it should be. Thank you very much for you continues help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the converter. Problem could be solved by getting primitive type value(i.e. integer,string...) from jsf component, or creating a custom converter for classes and referencing it in component(attribute: converter).

Comment: HI NikolaB, Tried all, but no good, i ve updated the question with more code.

Comment: HI Nikola, Really appreciate your help.But I tried all the things, I have been testing this with firefox, there is no error in the firebug console, I even restarted the machine hoping it will work. But so far no good. I dont what else to be done, May i try your workaround with primeface? what need to be changed for primeface?

Comment: HI NikolaB, I changed `<f:selectItems value="#{location.categories}" var="y" itemLabel="#{y.title} (#{y.itemCount})" itemValue="#{y}" />` itemValue to get the id of the `y` object, like this `itemValue="#{y.Id}"`. Guess what, it worked. Also i used '<f:ajax listener="#{location.onNodeSelect}" event="change" render="itemsPanel" execute="@form"/>` as well. Its working now as it should be. Thank you very much for you continues help. Really appreciate it.